# How far distance a 14 dBi 5.8 GHz panel antenna can reach?

Tags: antenna

I wonder what’d be maximum distance it can reach if we consider it’s line of sight and propagation losses are minimum.

Comment: The signal emitted by an antenna reaches infinitely far.  Over how much of that infinite distance you can detect it depends on the sensitivity and gain of your receiver as well as the emitted power at the source.

Comment: Line of sight at sensible antenna height at both ends. What antenna at other end? Std path loss  formula applies. Raleigh fading to be watched if either antenna is too  close to ground or there are high spots near the path. Obviously receiver sensitivity needs to be >= Tx power - path loss. But, line of sight.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I mean, one end is a 14 dBi panel antenna and the other one is just a cell phone WiFi antenna.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon speaking of std path loss formula, what’s acceptable and ideal free space path loss should be?

Comment: @Burak  - Google is your great friend: || [Path loss](https://www.google.com/search?q=path+loss&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&oq=path+loss&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j69i60j69i65l2j69i60l3.2431j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) || Wikipedia [Path Loss](https://wiki2.org/en/Path_loss) -  Wikipedia [Free Space Path Loss](https://wiki2.org/en/Free-space_path_loss)  Images with links [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=path+loss&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&sxsrf=ALeKk02xesVC2tvYsqjPL1tqJzQC_jPToA:1590131720993&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi1u4Cj9sbpAhWOzTgGHaSdA1EQ_AUoAXoECDEQAw&biw=2457&bih=1269)

Comment: @BurakAktas Note also [Fresnel zones](https://wiki2.org/En/Fresnel_zone)

Comment: @BurakAktas an antenna doesn't "reach" anywhere, it's a transmitter-receiver system that works over a distance. Without you defining what you want to achieve over the distance, the answer is "potentially infinity, but maybe also 0 m, or something in between"

Answer (score 0):

You would usually start with what would be an acceptable input SNR, based on information of the modulation, datarate, etc. For a rough estimate, you can get this out of the [Shannon-Hartley channel capacity equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem). If you use error-correcting codes, as a rough estimate, you can consider the coding gain before your SNR, ie, your SNR can be reduced by the coding gain.

$$ C = B\cdot \log_2\Bigg(1+\frac{S}{N}\Bigg)$$

Most communication standards will actually have more detailed signal requirements in their spec, which you should obviously use if they exist.

Once you figure out SNR, you can estimate needed RX power from SNR and [thermal noise equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise):

$$ P_n = kTB$$
$$ P_{rx} = SNR_{abs}\cdot P_n $$
$$ P_{rxdB} = SNR + P_{ndB}$$

So at this point, \$P_{rx}\$ is the signal power required at the receiver.

You can then figure out, using effective receiver antenna gain (which includes losses within the antennas) and RX power before the receiver antenna (note that in the case of a phone this might be negative gain, since the antenna efficiency is often very low):

$$ P_{rxantdB} = P_{rxdB} + G_{rxantdB}$$

We can do the same for the transmitter, using the effective transmitter antenna gain and output power:

$$ P_{txantdB} = P_{txdB} + G_{txantdB}$$

Now we know that the effective path loss that is acceptable is equal to:

$$ G_{channeldB} = P_{txantdB} - P_{rxantdB}$$

Which we can plug into out channel loss equations. If you just want to assume ideal, free-space pathloss, you can use the [Friis transmission equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friis_transmission_equation) which can be written as:

$$FSPL = \Bigg(\frac{\lambda}{4\pi d}\Bigg)^2 $$

Which when you think about it actually comes down to the fact that you 'spread' the transmitted power over the area of a sphere with radius \$d\$.

A method for including the effect of objects in proximity of the transmission path can be found in [Fresnel Zones](https://wiki2.org/En/Fresnel_zone). Even more complex models to estimate path loss in urban, forested or other environments, as well as including fading because of rain, can be found in various ITU publications on the topic.

---

Note that power is not just dB, but dB something - dBm, dBW, etc. I just write dB to indicate that I use one of these scales, after all the magic of dB is that it doesn't matter which you use, as long as you are consistent.

Also note that the more standard form of writing Friis transmission equations includes the antenna gains, but I separated the two here to clarify what is going on.

Comment: A comment on [Fresnel Zones](https://wiki2.org/En/Fresnel_zone) may be useful.